# Oracle SQL How to select multi column duplicates, splitting up their ids?

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

There are some functional duplicates in a database.

IE, in an example table clothes, if the columns country, color and type is the same, it counts as the same row.

I want to pull out these duplicates.

So given the example table:

```
Clothes
ID      COUNTRY     COLOR   TYPE
11      China       Blue    PJ
22      Spain       Red     Pants
39      Spain       Grey    Pants       
51      Spain       Grey    Pants                   
70      China       Blue    PJ
94      Spain       Red     Pants
```

I use the following query:

```
SELECT t1.id AS id_1, t2.id AS id_2
FROM clothes t1
LEFT JOIN clothes t2
    ON t1.type = t2.type AND t1.country = t2.country AND t1.color = t2.color
WHERE t1.id <> t2.id;
```

Which results in

```
id_1 id_2
51   39
39   51
70   11
11   70
22   94
94   22
```

Question: Is there any way to do it so I don't get the repeated rows? IE, what I'd like to have is something like:

```
id_1 id_2
51   39
70   11
22   94
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use distinct:

```
SELECT distinct least(t1.id, t2.id) AS id_1, greatest(t1.id, t2.id) AS id_2
FROM clothes t1
LEFT JOIN clothes t2
    ON t1.type = t2.type AND t1.country = t2.country AND t1.color = t2.color
WHERE t1.id <> t2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just making the `join`-condition asymmetric will do the trick:

```
SELECT t1.id AS id_1, t2.id AS id_2
FROM clothes t1
LEFT JOIN clothes t2
ON t1.type = t2.type AND t1.country = t2.country AND t1.color = t2.color
WHERE t1.id < t2.id;
```

Requiring that `t1.id < t2.id` will prevent the "swapped" pairs from appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I think ListAgg will solve your issue.

You need the ids that have same country, color and type combination.

```
WITH clothes AS
     (SELECT 11 ID, 'China' country, 'Blue' color, 'PJ' TYPE
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 22 ID, 'Spain' country, 'Red' color, 'Pants' TYPE
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 39 ID, 'Spain' country, 'Grey' color, 'Pants' TYPE
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 51 ID, 'Spain' country, 'Grey' color, 'Pants' TYPE
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 70 ID, 'China' country, 'Blue' color, 'PJ' TYPE
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 94 ID, 'Spain' country, 'Red' color, 'Pants' TYPE
        FROM DUAL)
SELECT   country, color, TYPE,LISTAGG(ID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) id_list
    FROM clothes
GROUP BY country, color, TYPE;
```

This will handle cases where there are more than 2 duplicates. In your query, join is used. So to handle more than 2 duplicates, you have to use multiple self joins.